# SQL Server Worker Threads Management and Understanding

Tags: sql-server, multi-thread

Hello SQL Server Community,

I'm trying to deepen my understanding of SQL Server's worker threads, especially with regard to the max worker threads setting in a busy OLTP system. I'm currently working with the `sys.dm_os_threads` DMV, and I'm exploring how best to optimize thread management on our server.

My current understanding is that SQL Server automatically manages the worker threads based on the system's workload if the default max worker threads setting is unchanged. SQL Server may allocate more worker threads to handle increased workloads and may reclaim or destroy these threads once tasks are completed, though this might not occur immediately.

However, I'm not entirely sure if my understanding is correct, particularly when it comes to situations where SQL Server may have reached its limit for creating new threads. If this happens and there are still new incoming requests, could this result in a 'deadlock scheduler' condition? We've recently experienced such an issue in our environment, and I'm trying to understand if this could be the cause.

Given this context, I have a few questions:

- On a busy OLTP system, should we consider altering the max worker threads setting from its default value calculated by Microsoft's formula?
- If we should change it, should this be to a number greater than the default?
- How can we best determine the optimal number of max worker threads for our specific environment to prevent the 'deadlock scheduler' issue?

Your insights or advice on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My current understanding is that SQL Server automatically manages the worker threads based on the system's workload if the default max worker threads setting is unchanged. SQL Server may allocate more worker threads to handle increased workloads and may reclaim or destroy these threads once tasks are completed, though this might not occur immediately.

This is correct.

> However, I'm not entirely sure if my understanding is correct, particularly when it comes to situations where SQL Server may have reached its limit for creating new threads. If this happens and there are still new incoming requests, could this result in a 'deadlock scheduler' condition?

It could, entirely depends on the situation. Assuming the system is chugging along and just hitting a resource limit, then new connections will fail, as a thread is needed to service those. That's typically what you'll start to see, along with the server being, "slow" or "sluggish", but that isn't a requirement.

Deadlocked schedulers happen when none of the current work makes forward progress, this is almost exclusively due to blocking.

> On a busy OLTP system, should we consider altering the max worker threads setting from its default value calculated by Microsoft's formula?

I would not, mainly due to the fact that you don't currently know why you had an issue. Let's say it is blocking (again, almost always is). You up the worker threads. Now, instead of having a deadlocked scheduler dump at 5 minutes, you get one at 7. No one actually root caused the issue, so the "solution" of course won't work. Are there caveats to this? Sure. Are those super edge cases? Yes.

There are multiple other things to consider, for example, artificially increasing thread count can make all other processes (not just SQL) and all other queries execute slower. Every threads need a slice of the CPU pie. If there are 800 threads on 4 cores, they get so much. If there are 2400 threads on 4 cores, you get even less (assuming the threads need to do work, just spinning up 2400 threads won't really accomplish anything if they don't have something to do).

> How can we best determine the optimal number of max worker threads for our specific environment to prevent the 'deadlock scheduler' issue?

You don't, the default number is a fairly good one, in general. The number of threads itself (assuming it wasn't set extremely low to help force the situation) is not the issue. Root cause the issue of the deadlocked scheduler first. Changing the MWT value is almost always not going to help and be more of a hindrance.